# iOS and Go - Keep-Alive using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, web-services, http, go, nsurlsession

In my iOS app, I have a search feature that fetches results from a server. The search updates live as the user updates their query, so this results in several requests being made in succession.

So my question is, how can I ensure that TCP keep-alive is being used on these connections? I'd like to reduce as much latency as possible, so it's important that a connection be maintained after the first request and reused for the following requests.

I'm using NSURLSession, and I've heard that it employs keep-alive by default, but how can I know for sure? Logging the requests on the server show no difference between each successive request, but I wouldn't expect to see any change just from the header information.

Any help here? I'm using Go on my server, so it's possible that it needs some additional configuration on that side too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you're confusing TCP keep-alive with HTTP keep-alive (persistent connections). These are unrelated concepts. From your question, you probably mean HTTP persistent connections.

In HTTP/1.1, persistent connections are the default and are used by `NSURLSession` and nearly every HTTP/1.1 client. You have to ask to turn them off. You can check for a `Connection: close` in the HTTP header, or on the server side, you can check the `Close` field of the `http.Request`. But I'm sure you're getting persistent connections. This means that you don't have to renegotiate the TLS tunnel (or at a minimum the TCP three-way handshake) for every request. (Though if you make parallel requests, there will still be multiple connections that you have to negotiate. HTTP/1.1 can only handle one thing at a time, and `NSURLSession` will try to use a pool of connections to improve response times.)

TCP keep-alives are a completely different thing. It sends a periodic "ping" to the other side to make sure it's still reachable. There are many ways for you to lose network connectivity and not know it until the next time you try to communicate, and the normal symptom is that the connection just hangs and you need to time it out. In theory TCP keep-alive is just the tool for discovering this, but I have almost never found it practical. It's difficult to configure properly (especially in Cocoa). You will almost always need to build a higher-level "ping" functionality for your application rather than relying on this.

But bringing it around to your problem, HTTP/1.1 is probably fine for you as-is, but you're going to need to carefully manage your responses. If you make a new request for every letter and send back a massive response, then that's going to work badly. You're going to keep all your connection pool busy downloading things that you're going to throw away. You need to focus first on good algorithms. At a minimum, you probably only want to send a few results at a time and provide a "paging" approach in your API to ask for more results for the same search.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. I've made some significant improvements in the algorithm since the question was asked, most importantly implementing a timer so that the search only sends a request when the user stops typing for a moment. But I'm curious about the "paging" approach you mention - could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @hundley paging means that if there are more than some number of results, only the first set are returned, at later batches are retrieved by appending a request variable with what "page" you want. Think about how Google results come in batches. It only matters if the number of results can be large of course. Your "wait for a pause" is a very common technique and very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

To know for sure what TCP is doing, you can enable [CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1887/_index.html). From the docs:

> During normal development you can set this environment variable via Xcode's scheme editor. If you need to investigate problems outside of Xcode, you can set it programmatically using the code shown in Listing 1.
>
> Listing 1  Programmatically enabling CFNetwork diagnostic logging
>
> ```
> setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);
> ```
>
> You should do this right at the beginning of the app's launch sequence. Normally putting this at the start of main is sufficient, but if you have C++ static initialisers that use CFNetwork you'll have to run it before them.
>
> CFNetwork diagnostic logging starts up when you first use CFNetwork—or any framework, like Foundation, that uses CFNetwork—at which point it will print a message like that shown in Listing 2.
>
> Listing 2  An example of the CFNetwork diagnostic logging startup message
>
> ```
> 2014-10-28 14:23:37.115 QTestbed[2626:60b] CFNetwork diagnostics log file created at: /private/var/mobile/Applications/76531F40-3291-4565-8C75-0438052C83BC/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/CFNetwork_com.example.apple-samplecode.QTestbed_2626.nwlrb
> ```